# Reasoning behind statement L(P1) > L - (1/2)ε

Tags: analysis, riemann-sum

Hey Guys I'm studying this proof in real analysis and just this one line gets me:

Suppose that *f* is bounded and Riemann integrable on [a,b] and ε > 0 is given. Since *L* = sup{L(P): P is a partition on [a,b]} exists, there is a partition P1 of [a,b] such that

**L(P1) > *L* - (1/2)ε**

What exactly does this statement mean? and where does the 1/2 come from? 
I'm so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the definition of supreme. If $L<\infty$ is the supremum of a set $A$ of real numbers then

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists a\in A : a>L-\epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary the result holds for $1/2\epsilon.$

Probably you have encountered this in the middle of a proof and the reason for $1/2\epsilon$ is technical. Sure there is another term in the proof with the same $1/2\epsilon.$ Thus, when you add both terms you get the "familiar" $\epsilon.$

Comment: Thank you so very much :), Indeed in the ending of the proof you add them to give you a solid epsilon :D